# how to implement settings in android

Tags: android

I want to create a settings class one. I've created one myself right now. For example, I created a key switch called camera. This clicklistener how do I do this?

**SettingsActivity Class:**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
}
```

**Settings Activity XML:**

```
        <androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory
            android:key="the_key_to_retrieve_the_preference_in_code">

            <androidx.preference.SwitchPreference
                android:key="camera"
                android:summary="...."
                android:title="Camera" />

            <androidx.preference.SwitchPreference
                android:key="reset"
                android:summary="..."
                android:title="Reset" />

            <androidx.preference.Preference
                android:key="key"
                android:summary="subtitle"
                android:title="title" />

            <androidx.preference.Preference
                android:key="key2"
                android:summary="subtitle2"
                android:title="title2" />

            <androidx.preference.CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="key_for_check_box"
                android:summary="subtitle"
                android:title="title" />

        </androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow that steps
 1. In oncreate you should make default setting and put the in shared prefs like this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Key","Value");
editor.apply();
```

And here change the flag for if settings are default or not. So first time when user open app everything by default and you set default values when he changed something the flag of default is changing and next time he come back this step ignores
2. On each switcher you have to make check and get value from shared preferences like this.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("Key", "Value");
if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !name.equalsIgnoreCase("default")
{
    // Switcher change state
}
```

Optional: You could optimize it by adding one more flag to check were there any changes after last update in that case just go and update each switcher but this is the easiest way. Either you could check if user open app first time or not by adding on null check

Conclusion: Check if first time just put everything with default values from shared preferences -> than if change switcher state just change the same in shared pref -> when come back to setting activity extract all values from each switcher from shared preferences